# Automatic syncing of clipboard between Windows and OSX

Tags: windows, macos, synchronization, clipboard

I want to sync clipboard between my Windows and OSX box.

I am currently accessing the OSX machine using VNC and want to be able to copy-paste (i.e. select+copy on Mac and paste on Windows) between the machines without doing tricks such as ssh+pbcopy/pbpaste from the Windows box.

I tried [Synergy](http://symless.com/synergy), but it has an awful bug when Windows is the server, so that pretty much kills this solution.

Is there any free/cheap software to do it conveniently?

Answer (score 0):

You can still copy and paste through an open google docs document.

Answer (score -1):

You can try [ShareMouse](http://www.keyboard-and-mouse-sharing.com/) program.

Comment: one problem I had with shareMouse is that when Mac is the host, and you try to use VS2012, your mouse stops responding on the remote windows machine :(